# Is it possible to recover broken .tar file?

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I was archiving several large directories (a total of a few TBs in size) using the command:

```
$ tar -vcf directories.tar --remove-files dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ dir4/
```

Whilst manovering through GNU screen I accidently cancelled the proccess! (CTRL-C)

dir1 and dir2 are now deleted and can't a seem to access anything in the archive:

```
$ tar -tvf directories.tar 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
$ file directories.tar 
directories.tar: empty
```

Is there anyway that I can continue the archiving process so that it can complete properly or recovering the data from the broken tar archive?

I'm using Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: Are you sure this is all you did? I just tried to replicate your setup on SuSE and Ubuntu 16.04-LTS, and in both cases the `--recover` flag was not available (check whether it is on your system), but `tar` was able to read back all files except the last one. Whatever I attempted, `tar` never failed to recognize the file as one of its own.

Comment: What's the size of the tar file? Does it contain anything at all? What does the `file` command report back?

Comment: @LSerni  Yes I'm pretty sure this is all I did. It doesn't recognise the --recover flag.  How were you reading back the files?

@Alexander Yes I think you're on to something here. As stated above: 
`$ file directories.tar`
`directories.tar: empty`

Looking at the actual size though gives:
`du -h directories.tar`
`0       directories.tar`
So it seems that nothing was saved but doesn't it check that it's added to the archive before it deletes the original?

Comment: This is very strange. It should not have deleted the files unless they had been indeed archived. Has free disk space increased at all? *Was* there enough disk space? Is it possible that the TAR file is actually elsewhere (e.g. you launched `tar` twice or something like that? I myself did such more than once).

Comment: @LSerni Thanks for all the help. Yes the amount of free space has significantly increased and thinking about it the disk would have been very close to maximum capacity. Is this a terrible mistake for me to make? How would I find out that I launched tar twice and what would happen to the data?

Comment: It's not a 'terrible mistake' - but I'm afraid the consequences might not be easy to revert. If the free space has increased, this means that the original data was indeed lost, without backup. I would immediately clone the disk - including the free space - on another, to see whether it's possible to use tools like ext4undelete.

Comment: Thanks @LSerni, that's all really useful info. If you want to write that all up as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tar file is empty, then there is no data to recover anything from.